# trying to show JTextField over JTable using gridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

I am trying to put the JTextFild over the JTable using GridBagLayout but the thing is only one component is showing.  That means I have to add a JPanel for each component, because I tried to add both of them in on a JPanel, then I tried to add them to the container.

The piece of code:

```
  package AnimeAid;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;


/**
 *
 * @author isslam
 */
public class GuiInterface extends JFrame {
    JTable table;
    JTextField enterText;
     public static void main(String[] args) {
     GuiInterface is = new GuiInterface("t");
     is.setVisible(true);
     }

    public GuiInterface(String title){
    setSize(900, 700);
    setTitle(title);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(GuiInterface.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    String[] columnNames = {"#","Start","End","Translation column"};
    Object[][] data = {
    {"1", "00:00:01,600","00:00:04,080", "Mr Magnussen, please state your\n" +
    "full name for the record."},
    {"2", "00:00:04,080 ","00:00:07,040","Charles Augustus Magnussen."}};
    enterText = new JTextField();

    table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
    table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    table.setAutoResizeMode( JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS );
        TableColumn columnA = table.getColumn("#");
        columnA.setMinWidth(10);
        columnA.setMaxWidth(20);
        TableColumn columnB= table.getColumn("Start");
        columnB.setMinWidth(80);
        columnB.setMaxWidth(90);

        TableColumn columnC= table.getColumn("End");
        columnC.setMinWidth(80);
        columnC.setMaxWidth(90);

        JPanel textFiled = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        textFiled.add(enterText);
        GridBagConstraints co = new GridBagConstraints();
        co.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        co.gridx =0;
        co.gridy =0;
        co.weightx=0.5;
        co.weighty=1;
        co.gridheight=0;
        co.gridwidth=0;
        co.ipadx=900;
        co.ipady=80;
        co.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;
        co.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 0, 0);
        textFiled.add(enterText,co);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        add(scrollPane);

        Container cp = getContentPane();
        cp.add(textFiled);



    }}
```

how it should look like but what happen is only one component are showing in the JFrame why
and How to show all the Component

[image: example]

Comment: You are adding the table to the `JPanel` and also to the `JFrame`

Comment: so do i have to remove it from the frame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the text field to the `NORTH` position of the default BorderLaoyout. Instead of this

```
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
    add(scrollPane);

    Container cp = getContentPane();
    cp.add(textFiled);
```

Just do this

```
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
    add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    add(textFiled, BordderLayout.NORTH);
```

Also why in the world are you adding `enterText` into `textFiled` twice. You may want to remove one of the.

Comment: still the same issue peeskillet is there a way to fix this with out using borderlayout only by using gridBaglayout

Comment: The JFrame already has a defult BorderLayout. You're just making use of it. When you just `add(scrollPane)`, you're actually doing this `add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER)`

Comment: Also i just checked it and I dont have that problem. The only changes I made were the one in my code

Comment: now i get it i have to remove the Container cp = getContentPane();cp.add(textFiled); ok any idea about gridbaglayout and aslo i this going to effect the application if i remove it or JScrollPane are doing the same job

Comment: It's a good idea to wrap the JTable in the JScrollPane, in case the table gets larger than the size. You can always set the preffered size of the JScrollPane if you want it a certain size

Comment: but can i do what you did only by using gridbaglayout

Comment: You need to set the layout of the frame to GridBagLayout or add both to the panel with the GridBagLayout

Comment: but the table are in the JScrollPane so if i tried to put the table in a normal JPanel i am going to lose the JScrollPane so is there a way to Control the layout for the JScrollPane

Comment: Put the scroll pane and the text field in to a panel with GridBagLayout with the correct restraints. Its not that hard to understand. And add _Only_ that panel to the frame